# Yslow alternatives - Optimisations for small websites

Tags: optimization, caching, yslow

I am developing a small intranet based web application. I have YSlow installed and it suggests I do several things but they don't seem relevant for me.
e.g I do not need a CDN. 
My application is slow so I want to reduce the bandwidth of requests.

1. What rules of YSlow should I adhere to?
2. Are there alternative tools for smaller sites?
3. What is the check list I should apply before rolling out my application?

I am using ASP.net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bandwidth on intranet sites shouldn't be an issue at all (unless you have VPN users, that is). If you don't and it's still crawling, it's probably something to do with the backend than the front-facing structure.

If you are trying to optimise for remote users, some of the same things apply to try and optimise the whole thing:

- Don't use 30 stylesheets - cat them into one
- Don't use 30 JS files, cat them into one
- Consider compressing both JS and CSS using minifiers or the YUI compressor.
- Consider using sprites (images with multiple versions in - eg button-up and button-down, one above the other)
- Obviously, massive images are a no-no
- Make sure you send expires headers to make sure stylesheets/js/images/etc are all cached for a sensible amount of time.
- Make sure your pages aren't ridiculously large. If you're in a controlled environment and you can guarantee JS availability, you might want to page data with AJAX.

Comment: Most of those (with the exception of YUI compression) will only have a small effect on the total bandwidth but they should all help savage the number of requests. Cutting down the number of requests can make a severe difference on an overloaded system.

Answer (score 1):

To begin,

1. limit the number of HTTP requests
   made for images, scripts and other
   resources by combining where
   possible. Consider minifying them
   too. I would recommend [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) for debugging HTTP
2. Be mindful of the size of Viewstate,
   set EnableViewState = false where
   possible e.g. For dropdown list controls
   that never have their list of items changed,
   disable Viewstate and populate in
   Page_Init or override OnLoad. [TRULY
   understanding Viewstate](http://infinitiesloop.blogspot.com/2006/03/truly-understanding-viewstate.html) is a
   must read article on the subject

Oli has posted an answer while writing this and have to agree that bandwidth considerations should be secondary or tertiary for an intranet application.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered [Page speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) since asking this question. Its not really for smaller sites but is another great fire-bug plug-in.

**Update:** As of June 2015 *Page Speed* plugins for Firefox and Chrome is no longer maintained and available, instead, Google suggests the [web](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) version.

Comment: I really could not find this as a fire bug plugin, is it changed or I have missed something?

Answer (score 0):

[Pingdom tools](http://tools.pingdom.com) provides a quick test for any publicly accessible web page.